# db2 convert double to currency string

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I'm using odbc and php to query a db2 database. Is there a simple way to return a double as a string?

For example, when I do a query like this:

```
select doubleField
from table
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

I'm getting a value like this:

```
7.05000000000000E+002
```

I like to use a function like this:

```
select ConverToCurrencyString(doubleField)
from table
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

To get a value like this:

```
188.50
```

Comment: Check out the `VARCHAR_FORMAT` function [in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-9-4-1-188&lang=en)

Comment: ...if you're storing currency as a double, you have larger problems.  Like the fact that `.1` can't be stored exactly, so adding it together 10 times doesn't actually add up to `1.0`.  You _should_ be using `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL` (or a custom type backed by one).  Accounting departments get a bit worried when money appears/disappears in non-intuitive ways...